# hiding a static method vs overriding a non-static method

Tags: java

Using static methods does not take advantage of OOP, so methods are rather overridden, not hidden. Yet hiding of static methods exists in Java. Is it there only to help out in some hopeless cases?
What are the consequences of hiding a static method vs overriding a non-static method? Are there any cases when hiding should be preferred over overriding (up to the point to make a method static, which is usually decided on other merits)?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question ? Do you have an example in mind ? Hiding a static method and overriding a non-static method are two *very* different things, so what type of comparison do you expect ?

Comment: I think you're going the wrong way with this whole thing. Instead of deciding whether to prefer hiding or overriding, you should first decide, whether to prefer static- or instance-methods. The rest of the choice becomes pretty obvious once this decision is made.

Answer (score 2):

Java is an **object-oriented programming language** such that you should **always prefer an OO approach** from a pure procedural approach, in other words you should always prefer to override a method rather than hiding a static method. I would even say that **hiding a static method is a terrible approach** because it is very error prone, you should **alway prefix a call to a static method with the name of the corresponding class**